# how to fetch multiple documents from 5 different collections in solr provided all collections have a field(key) unique

Tags: solr, streaming, solrj, solrcloud, spring-data-solr

**Is it possible to fetch the documents from all different collections in parallel and return as a list of document in solrj/spring-data-solr**?

how to maintain the order for each collection as well.

for eg: i have 5 different collections A,B,C,D,E

all have alt_key as unique field in them and i should be able to get the document list with 5 different document or many when i query them with "alt_key"

NOTE: They are not nested documents and it is independent collections

Comment: Do you want to keep the order inside the single collection? i.e. first all documents from collection1, then from collection2, then collection3, etc.? In that case - do it in your controller/utility handler by having multiple clients running in parallel. If not, you can hack it by using manual sharding and a meta-core that contains a schema with all the common fields between the collections.

Comment: Thanks but i already tried it but it didn't work.  implemented using controller and repository logic to fetch from every collection separately.